# Display error message if the mobile device doesn't support jquery mobile version

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am developing HTML5, CSS3 web site with jquerymobile. I want to display an error message like "Your mobile browser does not support this application" like message **if the mobile device can't render the page well** or **if it can't apply jquery mobile styles**. I couldn't find a good article on this yet. So your help is highly appreciated.

As an example the application works fine on iphone but not in blackberry bold device. So I want to display such message for blackberry bold device users. I see that blackberry bold device doesn't apply jquery styles to controllers.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQM has a $.mobile.gradeA() function that returns boolean. Here is a list for JQM 1.1.0 of which browsers have "gradeA" support and return true. http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/04/13/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-1-0/#platforms

```
if(!$.mobile.gradeA()​){
    alert('Your mobile browser does not support this application.');
}​​​​​​​​
```

**Update** Please note that newer blackberry bold devices should return true for gradeA support. Anything blackberry 7 + is ok. Also note that a device can run jQuery just fine and still not style things appropriately. It is the css3 support that is lacking in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in two ways.

1) My preferred method is to have a HTML DIV that with the message your browser can't use jQuery and then using jQuery to hide it on page load. So if jQuery works, the user won't see it.

2) The other is to check if jQuery loaded correctly and is a function. I use it to see if a page has jQuery. But it might work for you.

```
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined' || typeof $ != 'function') {alert("This application will not work in your browser etc.");}
```

Hope this is of some help.